# Xcode 5 Multiple Errors with #import not importing a header file

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on implementing a search bar which searches a table view and I have a lot of errors.

Phrasebook.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Phrasebook : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; //name of phrase
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *translation; //translation of name

@end
```

Phrasebook.m

```
#import "Phrasebook.h"

@implementation Phrasebook

@end
```

PhrasebookTableCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhrasebookTableCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *translationLabel;

@end
```

PhrasebookTableCell.m

```
#import "PhrasebookTableCell.h"

@implementation PhrasebookTableCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Code of the .m file in question:

```
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    ERROR PhrasebookTableCell *cell = (PhrasebookTableCell *)[[self.tableView         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]]; ERROR

    // Configure the cell...
    ERROR if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PhrasebookTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  

reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; ERROR
    }

    // Display recipe in the table cell
    ERROR Phrasebook *phrasebook = [Phrasebook objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = phrasebook.name;
    cell.translationLabel.text = phrasebook.translation;

    return cell; ERROR
}
```

Errors:
1) Parse issue: Expected Identifier
2)ARC Semantic Issue: No visible @interface for 'PhrasebookTableCell' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:'
3)ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'objectAtIndex:'
4)Semantic Issue: Property 'nameLabel' not found on object of type 'PhrasebookTableCell *'
5)Semantic Issue: Property 'translationLabel' not found on object of type 'PhrasebookTableCell *'

Comment: Could you mark which lines you are getting your errors? Also, could you please post the PhrasebookTableCell.h file?

Comment: What's `PhraseBook`? A custom `NSArray ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting xcode and cleaning your project ? For 3) it looks like you are calling objectAtIndex on the class Phrasebook and not on a nsarray instance.

Comment: Lines marked with ERROR at the beginning and ERROR at the end are the troublesome lines.  Phrasebook is just a name of a class, (the view is meant to be a book of useful phrases).  I've cleaned the project and restarted xcode multiple times. Thanks

Comment: RE: Larme, 'Phrasebook' is a NSObject as declared in our Phrasebook.h and Phrasebook.m files

Comment: Phrasebook is a class, what do you expect by calling objectAtIndex on it?

Comment: @Justafinger Phrasebook is declared as a NSObject in Phrasebook.h (Added to the question)

Comment: By the way I am trying to make the search bar using some source code from the tutorial at [link](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) aswell as following the tutorial.

Comment: Phrasebook is a class that extends NSObject. The error 3) states that you don't have a method objectAtIndex for that class. In your tutorial, objectAtIndex is called on recipes which is an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

In line 3 of the .m file in question, you have double `[[` brackets, when a single `[` would be sufficient. Remove one `[]`pair and try again.

Like this:

```
PhrasebookTableCell *cell = (PhrasebookTableCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```